# How to get a NSDictonarys out of JsonArray?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, dictionary

I'm working on an iOS - Project, wich will display the followers from one Person.
There is a Webserver running that gets Data from different Social Networks, save them with a Timestamp into an SQL Database. The iOS App makes a request and get a Json from the Sql Database. I converted the Json into an Array and printed it to the console.

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://getdata.php"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

NSError *error;
NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",json);
```

Output:

```
(
    {
    date = "2013-12-11";
    facebook = 107;
    instagram = 47;
    twitter = 42;
},
    {
    date = "2013-12-12";
    facebook = 107;
    instagram = 45;
    twitter = 42;
},
    {
    date = "2013-12-13";
    facebook = 107;
    instagram = 45;
    twitter = 42;
})
```

So what i want to do is to, is to compare the Facebook, Instagram an Twitter Followers with the day before. How could i do that: Get whole Object, where Date is Today. It will print out:

```
    date = "2013-12-13";
    facebook = 107;
    instagram = 45;
    twitter = 42;
```

Thanks for your help and sorry for my English!

Comment: Have you tried using NSDictionary instead of NSArray simply ?

Comment: What you have is an NSArray of NSDictionary objects.  To get an NSDictionary, index the array.

Comment: @nickAtStack - That would just misname the object and further confuse things.

Comment: Hint:  Look at the NSLog listing -- the `()` characters surround an array.  The `{}` characters surround a dictionary.

Comment: > " I converted the Json into an Array"   No, you did not. You just serialized the JSON into a representation which happens to be a hierarchy of Foundation objects, whose root object is either a NSArray or a NSDictionary.

Comment: And how to handle with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple for loop to enumerate all the dictionaries in your array. In order to compare the each day to the previous day, you have to start with an index of 1, like so:

```
for (NSUInteger i = 1; i < json.count; i++) {
    NSDictionary *currentDay = json[i];
    NSDictionary *previousDay = json[i-1];

    // Compare the follower counts for each social network here
}
```

Comment: That is a perfect idea, its working! But in case the Webserver didn't update the values. It takes the value from the fore day. Is there way to look for the date? If date = today get Dictionary?

Comment: @user3123470 Yes, there is, but that's a different question and so should be asked as a separate question.

Comment: _How could i do that: Get whole Object, where Date is Today._ That was part of my question, but it would be nice, if you could answer the second question.

Comment: Convert the `NSString` from each dictionary into a `NSDate` and compare to the current date. Keep in mind the `NSDate` is holds both the date & the time so you'll want to normalise the `NSDate` for _today_ to midnight. A combination `NSDateComponents` and `NSCalendar` will help with that. Then the comparison is a matter of calling `compare:` and looking for `NSOrderedSame`.